# Value for ASPX Dropdown list is not being set to correct value

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind a drop down list using this C# code:

```
var ctype = db.ComplaintTypes
    .Select(r => new { r.ComplaintTypeID, r.Description })
    .ToList();
ddlComplaintType.DataSource = ctype;
ddlComplaintType.DataTextField = "Description";
ddlComplaintType.DataValueField = "ComplaintTypeID";
ddlComplaintType.DataBind();
```

Code populates the dropdown however the index count is off by 1.  So ComplaintTypeID has a value of 1 in the data table but the code is returning a value of 0.  Which causing the app to crash for an invalid ComplaintTypeID.

If I add `ddlComplaintType.Items.Insert(0, "** Please Select**");`

It works but that causing my aspx required field validator to not work.  How can I correct the code to show the correct datavalue ?

Comment: I assume you're mixing up `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex`

Comment: You can insert a "Please Select" default item. The `RequirdFieldValidator` just needs a [`InitialValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_RequiredFieldValidator_InitialValue) then. `ddlComplaintType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "-1"))`. Here you assign `-1` as `InitialValue` to the validator.

Comment: You were correct #fubo  I was using the SelectedIndex.  Thanks